# How to get part from URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Well sorry for the probably misleading title. Wasn't sure how to describe it better.

When accessing the `status` page I want to get the attached ID. But I don't want to use GET fields (wordpress makes `/status?id=2134` to `/status/?id=1234` - that's the only reason actually).

So this is my url

```
http://foo.bar.com/status/1234/
```

I want to get `1234`

Okay fine. I could use something like `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` + `trim()` for example. Probably regex would be the key to get this job done since one could do something like `/status/1234/foo/bar/baz/..` But I'm wondering if there is something builtin with PHP to get this part of the url.

Comment: what i do: `explode('/',parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));`

Comment: @Dagon yeah that's neat. even a better solution than regex. But replace `parse_url(..)` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Feel free to post this as answer btw

Comment: $url is the url in question

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parse_url()` function, and extract it:

```
$url   = 'http://foo.bar.com/status/1234/';
$path  = trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
$items = explode('/', $path);
$num   = array_pop($items);
var_dump($num);
```

You can also use a regular expression, if that tickles your fancy:

```
$url  = 'http://foo.bar.com/status/1234/';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
preg_match('~/status/(?P<num>\d+)/?~', $path, $result);
$num = isset($result['num']) ? $result['num'] : null;
var_dump($num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present using `parse_url`, explode it using `explode` and finally select status id using `end`

Try like this

```
$url   = 'http://foo.bar.com/status/1234/';
$statusId = explode('/',trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
print end($statusId);
```

Demo Ex http://ideone.com/34iDnh

`trim`-  http://php.net/trim

`explode`-http://php.net/explode

`parse_url`-[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php